# Why isn't there any Design tool in Dart editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I have started using Dart editor for web app development. But there is no design tool(drag and drop like that of Visual studio, Eclipse Android IDE etc.). Not having a designing tool is kind of headache as I have to create buttons and other elements in html code.
Can you tell me if there is a better solution. Or maybe a designing utility in Dart editor itself and that i couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself - 'Dart editor'. It's not an IDE and unlike .NET it has no supplied UI toolkits like WinForms or WPF or whatever. Dart itself is a general purpose language. Presumably there are third-party, people working on various UI toolkits and designers, or bindings for existing ones like QT. But I don't think you'll see one from Google anytime soon.

This is essentially the same situation as the early days of Java, and similar indeed to .NET - the difference is that there *are* official GUI toolkits from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you very much. It'll be nice to have an IDE by Google but as you said, it's probably not possible any time soon.